# anchor build: error: toolchain 'solana' is not installed

Tags: anchor

I use this command of anchor, but there is some wrong with it:

```
levi@LEVI-104-PC:/opt/solana/youtube-tutorial/mint-nft$ anchor build
error: toolchain 'solana' is not installed
```

My specifications:

```
Windows11, wsl2: ubuntu 20.04,
rustc 1.72.0 (5680fa18f 2023-08-23),
solana-cli 1.16.28 (src:8a9f5026; feat:2294205250, client:SolanaLabs),
@coral-xyz/anchor-cli@0.29.0(by avm install latest)
```

Comment: already fixed: delete `~/.cache/solana`